# PHP Pagination query failed

Tags: php, mysql

I am receiving a pagination error in my php script. The query works fine when being ran directly inside mysql workbench and comes back with the proper results.

Error Returned: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 20' at line 2

```
    $getpositive = "select case_number, c.name as subject, a.name, u.first_name, u.last_name from cases as c join cases_cstm as cc on c.id = cc.id_c
                left join accounts as a on a.id = c.account_id left join users as u on u.id = c.assigned_user_id where rating_c ='1';";
$db -> PS_Pagination($getpositive, 20, 5, "");
$db -> setDebug(true);
$rs = $db->paginate();
$positive_rating_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs);
```

I am then displaying those results in a table:

```
while($val = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) 
        {          

        ?>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="7%"><?=$val['case_number']?></td>
                    <td width="40%"><?=$val['subject']?></td>
                    <td width="40%"><?=$val['name']?></td>
                </tr>
```

Here is my pagination function:

```
public function PS_Pagination($sql, $rows_per_page = 10, $links_per_page = 5, $append = "") {
    //$this->conn = $connection;
    $this->sql = $sql;
    $this->rows_per_page = (int)$rows_per_page;
    if (intval($links_per_page ) > 0) {
        $this->links_per_page = (int)$links_per_page;
    } else {
        $this->links_per_page = 5;
    }
    $this->append = $append;
    $this->php_self = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
    if (isset($_GET['page'] )) {
        $this->page = intval($_GET['page'] );
    }
}

public function paginate() {
    //Check for valid mysql connection
    if (! $this->IsConnected()) {
        $this->SetError("No connection");
        return false;
    }

    //Find total number of rows
    $all_rs = @mysql_query($this->sql );
    if (! $all_rs) {
        if ($this->debug)
            echo "SQL query failed. Check your query.<br /><br />Error Returned: " . mysql_error();
        return false;
    }
    $this->total_rows = mysql_num_rows($all_rs );
    @mysql_close($all_rs );

    //Return FALSE if no rows found
    if ($this->total_rows == 0) {
        if ($this->debug)
            //echo "Query returned zero rows.";
        return FALSE;
    }

    //Max number of pages
    $this->max_pages = ceil($this->total_rows / $this->rows_per_page );
    if ($this->links_per_page > $this->max_pages) {
        $this->links_per_page = $this->max_pages;
    }

    //Check the page value just in case someone is trying to input an aribitrary value
    if ($this->page > $this->max_pages || $this->page <= 0) {
        $this->page = 1;
    }

    //Calculate Offset
    $this->offset = $this->rows_per_page * ($this->page - 1);

    //Fetch the required result set
    //echo $this->sql . " LIMIT {$this->offset}, {$this->rows_per_page}";
    $rs = @mysql_query($this->sql . " LIMIT {$this->offset}, {$this->rows_per_page}" );
    if (! $rs) {
        if ($this->debug)
            echo "Pagination query failed. Check your query.<br /><br />Error Returned: " . mysql_error();
        return false;
    }
    return $rs;
}
```

Comment: Posting the actual error message might help... also an excerpt of your $db class (and specifically the PS_Pagination and paginate functions) would help.

Comment: I added the error. I am not sure where the paginate functions are located.

Comment: Apparently one of the functions is modifying your query (at least adding the `LIMIT 0, 20` bit), so it would be critical to see the function responsible for this. Otherwise we can't possibly come up with a solution.

Comment: @ipengineer If you don't know where the paginate functions are located how do you expect to fix them? What kind of answer are you looking for that doesn't involve changing code?

Comment: @Mike B I was able to locate the pagination code. I was not following. I thought I had an issue with my query not my pagination function. I have edited my original post. -Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `;` at the end of your query, and you're then trying to add `LIMIT 0,20` to the end. So it looks like this: `blah blah blah where something=value; LIMIT 0,20`. This won't work. Remove the `;` to fix.

Side note, you may be interested in the [`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) syntax, as this will greatly optimise your pagination method.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement has a semicolon at the end. I'm guessing that the `PS_Pagination` method just appends `LIMIT 0, 20` to your query, so it's coming out like `SELECT blah blah; LIMIT 0, 20`, which isn't valid SQL.